# How to load multiple html files by using wkhtmltopdf with other options in a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, wkhtmltopdf

I'm trying to combine multiple html files into one pdf file by using [wkhtmltopdf](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html)(ver 0.12.6) in a batch file, besides there are some options need to work with.

Since the number of html files that I need may changes before running my batch file, I move all of them in a folder. Therefore my goal is to load all the html files in the folder, add some options I need, and call wkhtmltopdf to generate the pdf file.

Here's what I've done:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set TARGET=Result

:: go to the folder with lots of html files and one css file
cd .\myfolder

:: convert to a pdf file
wkhtmltopdf ^
--enable-local-file-access ^
--user-style-sheet %TARGET%_Report.css ^
(FOR %%A IN ("*.html") DO %%A) ^
%TARGET%_Report.pdf

cd..
pause
```

Sadly it can not work. I think the problem is I can not use FOR loop in this way, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Here's the error message. Please give me some advise, thank you!

```
Loading pages (1/6)
Error: Failed to load http:/, with network status code 3 and http status code 0 - Host  not found
Error: Failed loading page http: (sometimes it will work just to ignore this error with --load-error-handling ignore)
Error: Failed to load http:/, with network status code 3 and http status code 0 - Host  not found
Error: Failed loading page http: (sometimes it will work just to ignore this error with --load-error-handling ignore)
Error: Failed to load http:/, with network status code 3 and http status code 0 - Host  not found
Error: Failed loading page http: (sometimes it will work just to ignore this error with --load-error-handling ignore)
Error: Failed to load http:/, with network status code 3 and http status code 0 - Host  not found
Error: Failed loading page http: (sometimes it will work just to ignore this error with --load-error-handling ignore)
Error: Failed to load http://in/, with network status code 3 and http status code 0 - Host in not found
Error: Failed loading page http://in (sometimes it will work just to ignore this error with --load-error-handling ignore)
Error: Failed to load http://do/, with network status code 3 and http status code 0 - Host do not found
Error: Failed loading page http://do (sometimes it will work just to ignore this error with --load-error-handling ignore)
Exit with code 1 due to network error: HostNotFoundError
```

Comment: Of course, you cannot use a `for` loop within an argument of another command. So you will have to build the list of HTML files within a variable in advance (using a `for` loop) and use that variable in the `wkhtmltopdf` command line then. Please use the search facility on top of this page to find out how to get such a [list of files](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbatch-file%5D+list+of+files+variable) into a variable…

Comment: thanks a lot, I solved it by using this and use `%files%` while calling wkhtmltopdf: 
`set "files="
for %%F in ("*.html") do (call set files=%%files%% %%F)`

Answer (score 0):

Please try my code

echo on

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /s "D:\source folder*.html"') do "directorywkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe" [-s A4] "%%a" "D:\OUTPUT DIRECTORY\pdf%%~na.pdf"

pause
echo off

I try this code and it works

But the result on result.pdf you must go to the last page of your pdf documents to see the result.

I still confused about the result :D
perhaps any helps more

Comment: Use special code formating